# Creating a Python type in C using an external library: ctypes or setuptools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, ctypes, python-c-extension

I'm writing some sort of Python C extension. It uses my own *.so library and headers from another project (let's say they're in `/usr/local/lib/otherproject.so` and `/usr/local/include/otherproject.h`).

I don't know which strategy to follow. I came up with two:

### As a pure Python extension

Write a Python C extension just as described [in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html). The problem here is that I don't know how to link with my own library and headers; to compile, I write a setup.py file and run `python3.4 setup.py build`. I don't know if I can include some option to the former command, or if I can write something in setup.py to include my headers and binaries (if so, I will also have to worry about making this distributable?).

### With ctypes

Write a C library (with my other project's build system). Include Python by passing `'/usr/include/python2.7'` to find headers and the  `python2.7` binary. Then use `ctypes` to wrap around that library and get the functions, types, objects, etc. The inconvenience here is that I need to manually wrap around every single function/type/variable from ctypes; I don't think I can use `PyModule_AddObject` since I'm not creating the module in C but in the Python wrapper (with ctypes).

---

Also, I tried the second approach, but I could not successfully get my custom PyTypeObject from ctypes. If the second approach sounds good to any more expert brain here on SO, I would post the code to get any help =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach also yields problems with distribution. And if you create a Python object in C you should do it in the context of a module. For scenarios where distribution is problematic, you could link this module statically instead.

For your issue with linking you'll find more information about [Library options](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options) in the documentation. Since your library resides in a directory which should be in the standard library search path, you'd only need to define your library with the `libraries` option of the `Extension` class:

```
mymodule_ext = Extension('mymodule', ['mymodule.c'], libraries=['otherproject'])
```

If you're not using the standard `lib*` prefix you'd need to use `libraries=[':otherproject.so']` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I did follow the first approach from above and yes, discovered ``libraries``, ``library_dirs``, and ``include_dirs``, which help me build like a Python extension and link with my other stuff.